# .htaccess Redirections with custom parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect the following link using .htaccess file

Old Url : `localhost/info.php?butter_cake-cid111.html`

To

New Url : `localhost/butter_cake/cid/111.html`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there only single URL to redirect or you have more? If yes then provide examples.

Comment: more than 1000                                                                                        Old Url : localhost/info.php?butter_milk-cid112.html

To

New Url : localhost/butter_milk/cid/112.html  and many more like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^-]+)-([a-z]+)(\d+\.html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^info\.php$ /%1/%2/%3? [L,NC,R=302]
```

`RewriteCond` is matching and capturing all the values that are to be used later in target URL. `?` in the end will strip off previous query string.

Comment: error : Not Found       /butter_cake/cid/111.html        the prefix http://localhost is not concatenated yet

Comment: see updated answer, make sure this is first rule in your .htaccess